# HTML CSS: div element height 100% when resized to + resolution

Tags: html, css, resize, height, resolution

recently i was coding a webpage and i bounced in to really annoying problem.

I have sidebar height 100%, but when i resize my browsers resolution to 150% and scroll all the way to the bottom i see a massive gap between my screen and my div tag.

Screenshot http://i58.tinypic.com/wrkl5y.png

MY CSS

```
    html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%
}

body {
    background: url(images/bg.png) #f7f7f7;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
      width: 1080px;
       min-height: 100%;
       overflow:hidden;

}

html, body{
  min-height:100%; 
    height:100%; 

}

#nav {
    background: url(images/navigacija.png) repeat-y;
    position: absolute;
      min-height:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    top:0; bottom:0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Sorry for my english, thank you for those who willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the #nav height to auto instead of 100% and remove the min-height property. Like this:

```
#nav {
    background: url(images/navigacija.png) repeat-y;
    position: absolute;
    height:auto;
    top:0; 
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
}
```